# Get the most voted with Mongoid and rails (something like count and group by)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mapreduce, mongoid

I have three documents

```
class User
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :votos
    ...
    ...
end

class Picture
    include Mongoid::Document
    has_many :votos
    belongs_to :user
    ...
    ...
end

class Voto
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :picture
    belongs_to :user
    field :value => :type => Integer
    ...
    ...
end
```

In the Voto document, the field value is a number between 1 and 5

So i need to get the most voted pictures of all to show...

How can i achieve this???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by querying also but it will take hell of a time and performance will decrease. The other solution is create a field `total_votos` in model Picture and whenever a vote is given to a picture add the field value into total_votes

```
class Picture
   include Mongoid::Document
   has_many :votos
   belongs_to :user
   field :total_votes,:type => Integer
   ...
   ...
end

class Voto
    include Mongoid::Document
    belongs_to :picture
    belongs_to :user
    field :value => :type => Integer
    after_create do
       picture = self.picture
       picture.total_votes += self.value
       picture.save
    end
    ...
    ...
end
```

and you can find the maximum value just by running the query

```
Picture.where(:max_votes => Picture.all.max(:total_votes))
```